# How to implement selectable DataRow in flutter

Tags: class, callback, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a dynamically sized `DataTable` in Flutter, and I would like to allow selection of `DataRow`s via checkboxes. I understand that each datarow has a `selected` and `onSelectChanged` attribute, but I don't know how to change a property of the `DataRow` itself using the `onSelectChanged` callback. I know I could add an array of boolean values to the containing widget's state and then edit with the callback, but that seems really slow and inefficient. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You change the property on the data you use to render the `DataTable` and then render it as `selected` when it was selected.

Comment: But doesn't that mean I have to re-render the entire table, since I am calling `setState`?

Comment: Yes, that's fine though. Flutter should reuse what didn't change

Comment: I tried this, but setState does not respond to changes

Comment: Please edit your question and post a minimal runnable reproduction. Prose won't get you a working solution.